# How to connect Phaser with Cordova

Tags: android, html, cordova, phaser-framework

I am using Visual Studio 2015 to develop html5 games, and have downloaded Phaser 2.4.6 and am trying to get an apk out. I can able to take out but Phaser is not loading...

HTML

```
<body>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/src/Phaser.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

index.js

```
document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

function onDeviceReady() 
{
    document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
    document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);
    var game = new Phaser.GAMES(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create });
    alert("Phaser Going Called...");
};
```

I didn't get an alert message that I initiated Phaser.

Comment: Is the above two different files? Or is that your HTML file? I also tried to clean up your question but I'm not sure what you mean when you say "I can able to take out but Phaser is not loading..."

Comment: Yes above we have 2 different files 1) Html 2) Javascript                                     I loaded the cordova , platformOverrides , Phaser  , index in HTML                            page, Using the index.js i tried to initiated the phaser using above phaser code but it is not started and below of the initiated we have a alert box that is not comes in game

Comment: If you run this just in a browser does it work? Any console errors? I think you're trying to attach the game to a div that doesn't exist too.

Comment: In the browser we don't have any problem it works perfect...but in the android we facing this problem...

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded VS 2015 Update 1 and installed the necessary bits for Apache Cordova support in Visual Studio.

Using a new project template I ended up with the following **index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <!--
        Customize the content security policy in the meta tag below as needed. Add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src to enable inline JavaScript.
        For details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617521
    -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>SimplePhaserTest</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <p id="deviceready" class="event">Connecting to Device</p>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/phaser.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.js** contains the following:

```
// For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397704
// To debug code on page load in Ripple or on Android devices/emulators: launch your app, set breakpoints, 
// and then run "window.location.reload()" in the JavaScript Console.
(function () {
    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
        document.addEventListener('pause', onPause.bind(this), false);
        document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);

        // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
        var element = document.getElementById("deviceready");
        element.innerHTML = 'Device Ready';
        element.className += ' ready';

        var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create })
        alert("Phaser Going Called ...");
    };

    function preload() {

    };

    function create() {

    };

    function onPause() {
        // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.
    };

    function onResume() {
        // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
    };
})();
```

Running this locally and then running on an Android device (Galaxy S4) resulted in the alert message as expected.

Maybe there was just some issues with bringing this over as a question, but some issues I saw in your code are both in your game creation:

```
var game = new Phaser.GAMES(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create });
```

That should be `new Phaser.Game(`, and you're adding it to an existing `div` with an id of `phaser-example` which isn't present in your example HTML.

It should be choking on the `new Phaser.GAMES` code in the browser as well, so I'm confused why you wouldn't be seeing an issue there too.

If it helps, I also have a working example of the above code in a [Git repo](https://github.com/JamesSkemp/cordova-testing/tree/131e73c11486b54cfe84da3b5da76a4f42659d2a) (linking to specific commit, in case I expand upon the repo in the future).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!! But problem is not solved, I copied your entire HTML code and Index.js code and put it in my coding....and i take the Phaser.js file from your GIT account and put it in my file and i tried to run the application just i got "Device Ready" text in device....that's it....Then i import your complete code and i create a project in Visual Studio also if i run there is no result from Visual studio..no browser pop-up too

Comment: This is starting to sound like a device issue if you're not seeing the alert even with a new project. What device are you using for testing? If you think it might be beneficial, I can update the project to actually use the game instance; there might be an issue with the `alert` call.

Comment: I've created a new project that just displays some text and the Phaser logo. I've created a README that walks through what I did to get to this point. It doesn't use an alert, so it may work better for you. https://github.com/JamesSkemp/cordova-testing/tree/master/Phaser%20Test%202